# Validation for Parsing Time in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm required to do validation for an SSRS report and hope that someone can help me out on this.

I'm trying to take a time string in the form of "h:mm" and parse it to time.

If the parsing is ok, run the report, if the parsing fails, I want to display a friendly error message on the report instead of getting "Local Report Execution Failed".

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two custom functions in your SSRS report like following.

```
'Parse the string and return a DateTime object representing the time
Public Function ParseTime(fTime As String) As DateTime
    Dim dtTime As dateTime = Nothing
    DateTime.TryParse(fTime, dtTime)
    Return dtTime
End Function

'Return error message if the parsing fails, otherwise return empty string
Public Function ParsingError(fTime As String) As String
    Dim dtTime As dateTime = Nothing
    If Not DateTime.TryParse(fTime, dtTime) then
        Return "Error converting time"
    Else
        Return ""
    End If
End Function
```

Then you can use those functions in the expression of the corresponding textboxes like this:

```
=Code.ParseTime(Parameters!TimeString.Value)
```

and

```
=Code.ParsingError(Parameters!TimeString.Value)
```

Hope it helps.